# Request blocks from EOS js

Tags: rpc

From the EOS-js [readme](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs), I've followed the instructions approximately. My understand is I do not need a signature for calls for data as I am not transacting. Fine, but what I do not understand is the new `JsonRPC` instance. It returns a `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

> Is the localhost string in this instance just filler text? Or is the eosjs library that I am importing actually spinning up a local instance of or node connecting to the EOS chain and from that local server I am supposed to retrieve data?

```
import { JsSignatureProvider } from 'eosjs/dist/eosjs-jssig';  // development only
const defaultPrivateKey = "5JtUScZK2XEp3g9gh7F8bwtPTRAkASmNrrftmx4AxDKD5K4zDnr"; // bob
const fetch = require('node-fetch'); 

const signatureProvider = new JsSignatureProvider([defaultPrivateKey]);
const rpc = new JsonRpc('http://127.0.0.1:8888', { fetch });
const api = new Api({ rpc, signatureProvider }); //required to submit transactions

(async () => { 
  await console.log(rpc.get_block(1)); //get the first block

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this line in ~/.local/share/eosio/nodeos/config/config.ini file

```
http-server-address = 127.0.0.1:8888
```

And restart nodeos `pkill nodeos` and start again.